# Android app crashes whenever i use imageview also the icon is not working on Nexus AVD

Tags: java, android

Stack Trace:

```
 06-25 20:56:30.143 3361-3361/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
06-25 20:56:30.143 3361-3361/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
06-25 20:56:30.145 3361-3361/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-25 20:56:30.271 3361-3361/com.example.testapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-25 20:56:30.360 3361-3374/com.example.testapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 31.278ms
06-25 20:56:30.370 3361-3374/com.example.testapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 392(62KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 48% free, 1097KB/2MB, paused 34.808ms total 65.457ms
06-25 20:56:30.375 3361-3361/com.example.testapp W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070066 (t=6 e=102) (error -75)
06-25 20:56:30.375 3361-3361/com.example.testapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
06-25 20:56:30.377 3361-3361/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 3361
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.ratingbar}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.testapp.ratingbar.onCreate(ratingbar.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.testapp:drawable/fpi" (7f070066)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070066 a=-1 r=0x7f070066}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1563)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.testapp.ratingbar.onCreate(ratingbar.java:12) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
06-25 20:57:03.942 3361-3361/com.example.testapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3361 SIG: 9
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".ratingbar">
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/fpi"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class ratingbar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ratingbar);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/fpi"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/fpi"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp">
        <activity android:name=".ratingbar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

My Android App Crashes whenever I use an Imageview. The app icon i provided is not working also.
This happens whenever I use the Nexus one Android Virtual Device. when I switch into another AVD like: pixel 2 or 3, it works fine.

--first time asking on stack. help me fix this please.

Comment: Please, add the stack-trarce of crash

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with this little information? Start by adding the stack trace along with the code that crashed it.

Comment: stack trace provided..please check